# Difference between と感じる and ように感じる

Tags: word-choice, nuances, word-usage

For example, is there any change in nuance if I replace ように with と (or って in casual speech) here:

日本人は他の国の人に比べて、相手の体を触ることにあまり慣れていないように感じます。

(The example is from a textbook lesson that discusses how in Japan it's less common to shake hands, high five or hug each other as a greeting.)

Comment: Off-topic, but is it 体を触る or 体に触る?

Comment: @L.F. Both are correct depending on the nuance you want to convey. を highlights the perimeter of the thing. 道を歩く walk through the path. 街を歩く walk through the town. Therefore 体を触る sounds as if talking about touching the whole body in a more general way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This nuance is quite simple:

Look at the following sentences:

```
I feel that a tornado is coming

I feel as if a tornado is coming
```

The difference is the strength of the assertion.

よう adds a bit of uncertainty.

```
なぜか彼が僕のことをわからないような気がします
```

I don't know why but I feel as if my boyfriend doesn't understand me.